# What does "rarely" mean in NASA's statement: "technically referred to as an exosphere because it’s so thin, its atoms rarely collide."?

Tags: atmospheric-science, gas, moon, nasa

The following statement is from [this article](https://www.nasa.gov/content/goddard/ladee-lunar-neon):

> The behavior of a dense atmosphere is driven by collisions between its
> atoms and molecules. However, the moon's atmosphere is *technically*
> referred to as an exosphere because it’s so thin, its atoms *rarely
> collide.*

However, it doesn't explain what is meant by "rarely collide". I find this strange, especially since the word 'technically' is used. There doesn't seem to be anything technical about such a vague definition. I mean, someone might think that the atoms of the atmosphere rarely collide at an altitude of 400 km above the earth's surface. So he or she might think that that must be exosphere, but it's not. It's the thermosphere.

The following statement is from [this article](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/LADEE/news/lunar-atmosphere.html#.VX6V-d9PbGI):

> However the moon's atmosphere is so thin, atoms and molecules almost
> never collide. Instead, they are free to follow arcing paths
> determined by the energy they received from the processes described
> above and by the gravitational pull of the moon.

Much the same thing in other words. I would have thought that between collisions atoms and molecules follow arcing paths whenever there is gravity. The higher the pressure the shorter the arcs, but arcs nevertheless. So this doesn't clarify anything for me.

So my question is: what does it mean to say that "its atoms rarely collide"? Does it mean they normally bounce off the moon rather than each other?

Comment: "Technically" doesn't always imply precision. It can also be used as a way to say "this is factually correct but generally irrelevant for the topic at hand".  Such as "Frank is the most Scottish person I have ever met, even though he is technically Irish". That doesn't answer your question, but it does counter the notion that "technically" somehow implies great precision.

Comment: Either you edit the question to ask about *specific* data or this is some exercise at semantics.

Comment: related:  https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/51391/is-it-possible-to-determine-whether-a-spacecraft-is-in-the-thermosphere-or-in-th

Comment: also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exosphere#Lower_boundary  "If we define the exobase as the height at which upward-traveling molecules experience one collision on average, then at this position the mean free path of a molecule is equal to one pressure scale height."

Comment: like all definitions for the boundary though, you are just going to get a rough estimate (which rapidly changes anyway depending on local conditions).

Comment: @eps "the height at which upward-traveling molecules experience one collision on average". One collision per *what*?

Comment: (i'm guessing, else I'd attempt an answer) per upward traveled distance of ~8.5km or 1 earth scale height. I think that the idea is that an upward traveling molecule at the exobase can travel just over 1 scale height between collisions.  So below exobase in thermosphere or lower, mean free path < 1 scale height, right at exobase, mfp = 1, in exosphere mfp > 1 .

Comment: On the face of it, there is nothing special or even interesting about "… it’s so thin, its atoms rarely collide…”

Can you say what worries you about “rarely” in that NASA statement?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Who said anything about it worries me?

Comment: I think that @Flater's comment is pretty appropriate.  NASA's been talking about Moon's atmosphere (like Flater is talking about how Frank is so stereotypically Scottish), but they want to note that it's not really an atmosphere at all, but an exosphere instead (like how Frank is actually Irish and not Scottish at all).  Nevertheless, they're giving only a hand-waving explanation of what the difference is (as if Flater added something vague like ‘Frank lives too far to the west to be Scottish’).

Comment: @MatthewChristopherBartsh Sorry if you've have preferred what "interests…" or "matters to" you. In all those cases, what's important to you?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Any given gas molecule goes a *long* way on average without colliding with another gas molecule. The mean free path for a gas molecule is on the order

$$ \lambda\sim \frac{k_BT}{d^2p} $$

where $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant, $T$ is the temperature, $d$ is the kinetic diameter of the molecule in question and $p$ is the pressure. Plugging in some rough values for the lunar environment gives

$$ \lambda\sim 10^5~\rm km $$

as a back of the envelope estimate. The moon's circumference is only $\sim10^4~\rm km$, so most gas molecules probably escape the moon's atmosphere or collide with the moon without ever colliding with another gas molecule.

Comment: How many times on average would an exosphere molecule strike the moon before escaping the moon's gravity?

Comment: @MatthewChristopherBartsh No idea.

Comment: If $k_{B} T$ ~ 10 eV, $d$ ~ $10^{-10}$ m, and $P$ ~ 1 nPa, then I am getting something like $10^{8}$ km.  Is my estimate for $d$ too small?

Comment: Note that on Earth at STP, the mean free path is ~60nm (nanometers, not nautical miles...)

Comment: @honeste_vivere $10~\rm eV$ corresponds to a temperature of $10^5~\rm K$, about twice the temperature of the sun's surface. Fortunately for the Apollo astronauts, the moon is much cooler than that. ;)

Comment: @Chris - No, the solar wind is routinely at ~10 eV or more [e.g., see https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2018ApJS..236...41W/abstract].  True, the regolith only gets up to about ~260 F in the sun, but the ionized gas around the moon is at much higher temperatures.  The solar corona is typically in the ~100 eV or more range.  Since any particle leaving the lunar surface will likely have more than the thermal energy (e.g., sputtering from ~1 keV ions), the "temperature" will be much higher than 260 F.

Comment: @honeste_vivere An energy of $10~\rm eV$ corresponds to a speed much higher than the escape velocity so presumably any such sputtering does not stay in the moon's atmosphere for long- if you even consider it to have ever been part of the atmosphere. [NASA measurements](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/moonfact.html) of the moon's atmosphere have its temperature range from $95~\rm K$ to $390~\rm K$.

Comment: @Chris - Ah okay, you are talking about neutral particles right near the surface.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Well there are some ions as well, and the particles can arc pretty high without escaping. But yes, I don't think that (relatively) high-energy particles that immediately escape during solar winds really count as "atmosphere" in the sense OP is asking about.

Comment: That mean free path is crazy. I'm used to the idea that atmosphere holds itself up through molecular collisions, but those particles seem not to ever hit each other, so why doesn't it just... fall down? Is it just elastic collisions with the ground (like little bouncing balls) or orbital trajectories from the solar wind?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Some of it does just fall down- its atmosphere is continuously being lost and replenished. Although presumably there are elastic collisions with the ground as well. (As there must be on earth, or our atmosphere would just fall down as well).

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: Indeed, that's the whole point of the question: NASA is saying that an exosphere is *qualitatively* different from an atmosphere, because the mean free path is on the same scale as orbital / escape distances.  So as you say, it's more like a bunch of stray molecules individually bouncing around for the duration they're near the moon at all.  (At least that's my understanding.)

Comment: What does the $\sim$ symbol mean? Don't you mean $\approx$?

Comment: @SomeGuy In this context, it typically means "on the order of," and is used for very rough approximations where we claim the order of magnitude is approximately correct but we don't claim even one significant figure.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Regarding elastic collisions: I guess it's not so much that the atmosphere particles bounce off the ground like ideal ping pong balls (although maybe they do, to some approximation). Rather, it's that if a gas particle's kinetic energy is roughly the same as the temperature of the surface (in units of energy per degree of freedom) then it's about as likely to gain energy from the collision as lose energy, because the particles it collides with are also moving.

Answer (score 17):

The phrasing is a reference to some of the assumptions made in the physics of gasses.  For gasses at a pressure level we are used to, like on the surface of earth, the mean free path length is very tiny (about 68nm at STP).  This means that a gas molecule undergoes a great many random collisions as it travels a distance.  By the central limit theorem, this makes the behavior of the gas very predictable in a statistical sense.  Many of our laws are formulated on these assumptions.

In rarefied gasses, such as the atmosphere of the moon, mean path lengths can be much longer.  At $2\cdot10^{-12}$ Torr, that atmosphere qualifies as "[ultra high vacuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_free_path)" with mean path lengths on the order of $10^5$ km!

This means many assumptions we make about how gasses work require more complex physics to model them.  In our atmosphere, it is very reasonable to assume that the velocity of a particle is almost uniformly distributed, and they travel in almost straight lines.  On the moon, we must account for the fact that particles have been under the influence of gravity for quite some time between collisions.

The practical differences show up in high vacuum chambers as well.  Turbo-pumps look a lot like fans, but they aren't designed to create pressure gradients.  The idea of a "pressure gradient" is not as meaningful in such vacuums.  Instead, the fan blades act more like baseball bats, knocking the gas atoms away.

Comment: @ruakh Thanks.  I have too much use for the word "reified."  Finger memory is strong!

Comment: Is "almost uniformly distributed" meant to read "almost normally distributed"?

Answer (score 13):

"Rarely" doesn't have a black-and-white, sharply-delineated definition, because there is no non-arbitrary cutoff for when things "almost never" happen (unless you're a mathematician - then "almost never happen" means "happens with probability $0$"; that's not the case here, though!).

The key point is that, the thinner a gas gets, the less and less likely it is for its molecules (including single atoms as "molecules") to collide with each other, because they're farther apart and so it is easy for an atom moving in any given direction to miss a lot of atoms before it finally finds one to collide with - if it ever does at all.

The reason though why this is important is that the usual "thermal" distribution of molecular speeds in a gas - the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution - comes about by repeated collisions of the gas molecules with each other. Note that if you think about the ideal gas model, there is no *a priori* reason that the molecules *can't* have any old speed distribution whatsoever: so that we model a gas as having this distribution must come from some sort of assumption. That assumption is collisions, and that assumption is what starts to fail here. In a sense, the gas starts to lack a well-defined "temperature" under generic circumstances.